# Confusing git message

Tags: git

I'm getting the weirdest message it git

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   folder/test.txt
#       modified:   tesitng.txt
# no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Which one is it? If I commit now, will there be changes added to the repo as the modified message shows or will there be `no changes added to commit` ?

Comment: Don't worry, you'll get much weirder ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are currently no changes added to the commit.  You are seeing the difference between the working directory, the staging area, and the final commit in git.

http://learn.github.com/p/normal.html has details on using the staging area that fairly well illustrate what is going on.

In your case, by the way, you have two modified files, and none of those changes are staged to be part of the next commit.

Comment: but when I type `git -a -m "msg"` it commits it just fine

Comment: Yes, it would: the `-a` means that you just did two things, stage all changes, and then commit.

Answer (score 1):

The changes are there in your working directory, you have to `stage` the changes - that is add to the index and say to git that these files can be committed. And then, do the commit.

Git is already telling you what to do:

```
 (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
```

This is one of basics of git, so I recommend you start with a tutorial on Git basics.

Comment: but when I type `git -a -m "msg"` it commits it just fine

Answer (score 1):

git is a bit more complex than other version control systems you might have used before.
There are three states that you have to discern:

1. modified - the file has changed, but will not be part of the next
   commit
2. staged - the file has changeed, the changes will be part of the next commit
3. commited - the file did not change since the last commit

you get to the first state you just change the file

to get from 1 to 2 you do a git add

to get from 2 to 3 you do a git commit

yes, it's in the manual http://learn.github.com/p/normal.html

Comment: but when I type `git -a -m "msg"` it commits it just fine

Comment: yes. the -a is a shortcut for "stage all the changes". that's convenient most of the time.  but some of the time you want to stage only some of the changes, then you have to do that step explicitly.